# Where can I find MPLS/BGP VPNv4 labels through SNMP (cisco IOS router)?

Tags: cisco, snmp, mpls

I'm implementing SNMP and i've been digging through MIBs for the past few days. I have managed to extract the equivalent of the show command 'show mpls forwarding-table' through the 'MplsLsrMib', but this show command does not contain the labels of associated with routes learned through BGP - only the locally generated labels. I've been digging through the VPN MIBs and all of the MPLS and BGP MIBs and so far i've come up with nothing. 
According the the "MIBs and RFCs" section of the documantations linked below i'm beggining to think that this information doesn't exist through SNMP on any MIB.
If anyone could shed some light on this I'd appriciate it immensely.
Thanks!
Docs:

- http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/fscsc22.html#wp1015347
- http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2s/feature/guide/fsiaslbl.html#wp1032445

EDIT: Thanks for the the comment, i'm using IOS 15.1(4)M2 and 12.4

Comment: You're referring to IOS 12.0 and IOS 12.2 docs. Please add the exact model and software version you're using to increase the chance of getting better answers.